# What is "maturity leave?"

Tags: benefits, leave

I just saw this ad on StackOverflow:

[image: job ad including "Maturity leave" as a benefit]

What is the advertised "Maturity leave?" Does it mean time off to care for parents/aging relatives, similar to how paternity leave is time off when an employee becomes a parent?

Comment: I'm almost certain they just spelled "maternity leave" wrong.

Comment: It's when you're just so mature now that you don't need to work anymore.

Comment: I suspect someone misspelled maternity as "maturnity" and then autocorrupt helpfully did its thing...

Comment: @reg, now that's some flowery language to advertise that you have a retirement plan!

Comment: I'd be more interested in a company that offered immaturity leave.  Spring break and Mardi Gras, here we come!

Comment: i VTC as off-topic. Reach out to SO jobs or employer and point to the type

Comment: Nothing about retirement or health insurance in the top 4 benefits, but hey we have white boards throughout the office!!

Comment: A search for the term shows that this seems to be a common mistake and/or auto-correct error.

Comment: This site has way too many votes to close, especially with excuses like "off topic" that don't necessarily apply, just because someone doesn't like something.

Answer (score 28):

Given that they have a baby carriage as the icon, it seems likely that it is a typo and they really mean "maternity leave", which is leave you get when you become a mother. Paternity leave is for new fathers (from the Latin word for father, "pater"). The company is advertising that they give leave for new parents of both genders, which is not always a given (especially in the US).